# Make "make" change-track two directories in one rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using GNU Make, but I'm willing to change to something else if necessary.

I've got two directories `ALPHABETIC` and `NUMERIC` with the following contents.

```
./ALPHABETIC:
A.txt  B.txt  C.txt

./NUMERIC:
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt
```

and a program `foo` which takes as input a file in `ALPHABETIC` and a file in `NUMERIC` and outputs something.

I want to create a rule such that: If a file `c` in `ALPHABETIC` changes, re-run `foo` on `c` and every file in `NUMERIC`. If a file `n` in `NUMERIC` changes, re-run `foo` on `n` and every file in `ALPHABETIC`.

Example: `A.txt` changes. Then what should happen is:

```
foo A.txt 1.txt
foo A.txt 2.txt
foo A.txt 3.txt
```

Let's say now `2.txt` changes. Then what should happen is

```
foo A.txt 2.txt
foo B.txt 2.txt
foo C.txt 2.txt
```

I tried doing this with pattern rules but it didn't work.

Comment: Does `foo A.txt 1.txt` produce an output file with a name that identifies it as the product of `A` and `1`? That would save some work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As make is designed to manage build systems that produce files from files, let's first assume that `foo A.txt 1.txt` produces a file named `A.1.txt` in the main directory. You could try something like:

```
.PHONY: all

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

ALPHA := $(patsubst ALPHABETIC/%.txt,%,$(wildcard ALPHABETIC/*.txt))
NUM   := $(patsubst NUMERIC/%.txt,%,$(wildcard NUMERIC/*.txt))

# $(1): ALPHA
# $(2): NUM
define ALPHANUM_rule
$(1).$(2).txt: ALPHABETIC/$(1).txt NUMERIC/$(2).txt
    @echo foo $(1).txt $(2).txt && \
    touch $$@

all: $(1).$(2).txt
endef
$(foreach a,$(ALPHA),$(foreach n,$(NUM),$(eval $(call ALPHANUM_rule,$(a),$(n)))))
```

Note the use of `echo` and `touch` to emulate the effect of your true `foo` command. The most important thing to understand is the `foreach-eval-call` construct, including the reason why some `$` signs need to be doubled (`$$`). See [The eval Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-eval) from the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) for a detailed explanation.

Demo (`host>` is the shell prompt):

```
host> make
foo B.txt 2.txt
foo B.txt 3.txt
foo B.txt 1.txt
foo A.txt 2.txt
foo A.txt 3.txt
foo A.txt 1.txt
foo C.txt 2.txt
foo C.txt 3.txt
foo C.txt 1.txt
host> make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
host> touch NUMERIC/1.txt 
host> make
foo B.txt 1.txt
foo A.txt 1.txt
foo C.txt 1.txt
host> make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
host> touch ALPHABETIC/C.txt
host> make
foo C.txt 2.txt
foo C.txt 3.txt
foo C.txt 1.txt
host> make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

But what if `foo A.txt 1.txt` does not produce a file? In this case, the simplest thing to do is to produce empty files anyway. We will create them in a separate directory for easier cleaning:

```
.PHONY: all

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

ALPHA   := $(patsubst ALPHABETIC/%.txt,%,$(wildcard ALPHABETIC/*.txt))
NUM     := $(patsubst NUMERIC/%.txt,%,$(wildcard NUMERIC/*.txt))
TAGSDIR := tags

$(TAGSDIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

# $(1): ALPHA
# $(2): NUM
define ALPHANUM_rule
$(TAGSDIR)/$(1).$(2).txt: ALPHABETIC/$(1).txt NUMERIC/$(2).txt | $(TAGSDIR)
    @echo foo $(1).txt $(2).txt && \
    touch $$@

all: $(TAGSDIR)/$(1).$(2).txt
endef
$(foreach a,$(ALPHA),$(foreach n,$(NUM),$(eval $(call ALPHANUM_rule,$(a),$(n)))))
```

There are two more things to understand:

- The use of empty files (`$(TAGSDIR)/A.1.txt...`) to keep track of what has been done already and when.
- The [Order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) `$(TAGSDIR)` used to guarantee that the directory containing the empty files is created before being used, without forcing re-builds every time its content is modified.